# Type ahead search does not work from Task Module

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I need to implement a scenario where type ahead search makes a call to my remote api and fills in the choice list. This works fine the if adaptive card is sent directly in the chat. But this not work inside if the adaptive card is sent in the task module.

### Steps

Following is the message which is sent for adaptive card

```
const card = CardFactory.adaptiveCard({
    type: 'AdaptiveCard',
    body: [
      {
        type: 'RichTextBlock',
        inlines: [
          {
            type: 'TextRun',
            text: 'Test',
            weight: 'bolder',
          },
          {
            type: 'TextRun',
            text: 'Test',
          }
        ],
        separator: parseInt(index) === 0,
        spacing: parseInt(index) === 0 ? 'extraLarge': 'default',
      },
     {
        title: 'Update',
        type: 'Action.Submit',
        data: {
          msteams: {
            type: 'task/fetch'
          },
          id: 'Upate Id',
          buttonText: 'Update',
        }
      }
    ],
    $schema: 'http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json',
    version: '1.5',
  })
```

Following is card which is sent in task module

```
const card = CardFactory.adaptiveCard({
    $schema: 'http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json',
    version: '1.5',
    type: 'AdaptiveCard',
    body: [
      {
          "columns": [
          {
              "width": "stretch",
              "items": [
              {
                  "choices": [
                  {
                      "title": "Static Option 1",
                      "value": "static_option_1"
                  },
                  {
                      "title": "Static Option 2",
                      "value": "static_option_2"
                  },
                  {
                      "title": "Static Option 3",
                      "value": "static_option_3"
                  }
                  ],
                  "isMultiSelect": false,
                  "style": "filtered",
                  "choices.data": {
                  "type": "Data.Query",
                  "dataset": "npmpackages",
                  "testkey": "harkirat"
                  },
                  "id": "choiceselect",
                  "type": "Input.ChoiceSet"
              }
              ],
              "type": "Column"
          }
          ],
          "type": "ColumnSet"
      }
  ],
    actions: [
      {
        type: 'Action.Submit',
        title: 'Save',
        data: {
          privateMeta,
          replyToId
        }
      }
    ]
  });
```

Following is the onActivityInvoke code:-

```
  async onInvokeActivity(context: TurnContext): Promise<InvokeResponse<any>> {
    if (context.activity.name === 'task/fetch') {
      const result = await this.handleTeamsTaskModuleFetch(context, {
        replyToId: context.activity.replyToId,
        data: context.activity.value.data
      });
      return {
        status: 200,
        body: result
      }
    }
    if (context.activity.name == 'application/search') {
      const successResult = {
        status: 200,
        body: {
          "type": "application/vnd.microsoft.search.searchResponse",
          "value": {
            "results": [
              {
                "value": "FluentAssertions",
                "title": "A very extensive set of extension methods"
              },
              {
                "value": "FluentUI",
                "title": "Fluent UI Library"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }

      return successResult;
    }
  }
```

Note that the activityInvoke function is not called when I enter the search text in my input box. However, if I send this card directly i.e without task module and directly in chat it works just fine.

Can someone please help me understand if I am missing something, is this a bug or the feature itself is not supported?

Comment: Could you please check if you are getting any errors in the console? Meanwhile we are checking this at our end.

Comment: Yes I am getting error `504: Bot is not installed`

Comment: The engineering team is working on the fix for this issue. We do not have any ETA to share.

Comment: This issue is fixed.

Comment: Hi, this is not working for me. I still get the same error of bot not installed. Can someone help me?

Comment: 0.2-angular-jquery.min-92954a0.js:114 2022-05-18T16:22:00.864Z [BotCardService:executeSearchInvoke()] invoke failed: bot not installed
0.2-angular-jquery.min-92954a0.js:114 {statusCode: 504, message: 'App is not installed'} undefined

Comment: Engineering team has confirmed that the fix should be available publicly by next week probably.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will check it out once next week!

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT I am still having this issue. Any feedback? Thanks!

Comment: @John - This same issue is being tracked here -https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/7932. Please track the github for further updates. Thanks.